# Automorphism of algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ f : \mathcal{M}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) \to \mathcal{M}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) $ be a morphism of $ \mathbb{C} $-algebras defined by $ f ( M ) = \overline{M} $ (conjugate matrix). $ f $ is an automorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras such that $ f(f(M)) = f^2 ( M ) = M $. It's an involution.
My question is :

> Can we find $ f : \mathcal{M}_{3} ( \mathbb{C} ) \to \mathcal{M}_{3} ( \mathbb{C} ) $ an automorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras  such that $ f(f(f(M))) = f^3 ( M ) = M $ ? How to do it ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: You ask for a not trivial automorphism? Otherwise it suffices to take $f=\operatorname{id}$

Answer (score 1):

All $\Bbb C$ linear automorphisms $\psi$ of the algebra $M_n(\Bbb C)$ are inner in the sense that there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that for all $X\in M_n(\Bbb C)$,
$$\psi(X)=PXP^{-1}$$
If $P$ satisfies $P^3=\mathbf 1$ and isn't proportional to the identity matrix then the associated inner automorphism is non trivial and its cube is the identity automorphism.